# Second form of ID for USPS form 1583 for American living abroad?

Tags: us-citizens, postal-system

US virtual postal mail services require the customer to provide the US Postal Service form 1583 which authorizes the mail service to receive physical mail on behalf of the customer.

Form 1583 requires two forms of identification, based on the following statements from section 8 of the form:

> Two types of identification are required. One must contain a
> photograph of the addressee(s). Social Security cards, credit cards,
> and birth certificates are unacceptable as identification.
>
> Acceptable identification includes: valid driver's license or state
> non-driver's identification card; armed forces, government,
> university, or recognized corporate identification card; passport,
> alien registration card or certificate of naturalization; current
> lease, mortgage or Deed of Trust; voter or vehicle registration card;
> or a home or vehicle insurance policy.

A passport will suffice for one form of identification.  **But how does one provide a second form when all other forms are based in the foreign country of residence?**  Would a foreign driver's license or residence card be accepted?  That seems unlikely.

Comment: In light of the fact that they accept identification cards issued by universities and private corporations, it seems unlikely that they would refuse to accept driver's licenses issued by foreign governments (or a lease, mortgage, or insurance policy for a property in a foreign country).

Comment: @phoog You are probably correct.  And based on my support question to the virtual mail service, it sounds like acceptance of the form is somewhat arbitrary.  It's not even clear if the judge of the form is a USPS employee or just the virtual mail service staff.